# Is it possible to have a "string template" and multiply that template with data and then obtain an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How I can get this kind of output (`wp[0]`, in this case, is an array as required for using waypoints for the Google Directions API)?

```
var wp = [
  [
      {
      location: 'oradea, ro',
      stopover: true
      },
      {
      location: 'bistrita, ro',
      stopover: true
      },
  ]
];
```

I have a string of locations in this format:

```
var locations = "oradea, ro&&bistrita, ro&&targu frumos, ro";
```

After splitting the string by `"&&"`, I will get each location that I need. And I was thinking to use a "template string" to generate the format I needed.

```
var template = "{ location: 'locationToReplace' ,stopover: true}";
```

But I have no idea how to convert everything to get an array at the end.

Is there another solution to reproduce the output type and format it as `wp[0]` that will give in the example from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you `split` the string, you can just `map` over it to transform it into the object that you want.

```js
var locations = "oradea, ro&&bistrita, ro&&targu frumos, ro";

const places = locations.split("&&");

var wp = [places.map(location => ({ location, stopover: true }))];

console.log(wp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the only thing I has to modify it was:    var wp = [places].map(location => ({ location, stopover: true }));